# How to run two cake file one by one based on first cake file compilation success?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I want to run my source compilation source.cake file and then compile Build.cake file But i should not start Build.cake if source.cake file has failures.So how to pass the compilation status of soruce.cake file value to build.cake ?

Is this possible in cake ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there's several ways to do this if your running under the Windows Command line or Bash you can just to the use the `&&` operator like this:

```
cake source.cake && cake build.cake
```

If your running PowerShell you can do the following

```
cake .\source.cake;if($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { cake .\build.cake }
```

Cake also has an alias to execute Cake scripts so you could also call source.cake from your build.cake the first thing you do like this in your `build.cake`:

```
//First line of build.cake
CakeExecuteScript("./source.cake");
//If above fails it'll throw an exception and stop executing build.cake
```